# Bluetooth PAN (tethering) error: 'failed to obtain ip address on bnep0'

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I'm trying to set up tethering for my Zero with an Android phone. So far I can login and use the terminal over Bluetooth but now I would like the Zero be able to access the Internet but I get this message: *'failed to obtain ip address on bnep0'*. This is what I have done so far: go to Bluetooth manager in GUI mode, click 'Devices', right-click on the device then select 'setup', chose 'Connect to group network'. First a message says 'Device added successfully' but then it says 'failed to obtain ip address on bnep0'. Do I need to add bnep0 in /etc/network/interfaces with an IP address?

Comment: Note that the Android device would have to provide an IP and routing for the Pi.   It can't just make one up for itself.

Comment: Great, thanks! What should I do on the Android side then?

Answer (score 1):

@goldilocks is right, the phone needs to provide IP address. Android setup:  Settings -> Tethering & portable hotspot -> Bluetooth tethering ON

Once the BT tethering is on, the RP can connect (use the Bluetooth manager).